# Given Premises (¬A|B), (¬C→B) and ((D&C)→A), prove the argument (¬B→¬D)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Given Premises (¬A|B), (¬C→B) and ((D&C)→A)

prove the argument (¬B→¬D) by using Laws of equivalence and rules of inference.

Without doing indirect proof or conditional proof, can anyone give me some idea of this question? I get stuck on this question for a couple of hours.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: To be stuck means that you have tried something.  Please show your work so far.

Comment: @GrahamKemp are we sure they can follow that logic ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove this with [rules of inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference)
 and [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence),
I think the key idea is to use Distributive laws, which is similar to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3409432):

**Hint:**

$~~1.~\neg A\lor B\\~~2.~\neg C\to B\\~~3.~(D\land C)\to A$

$$(\neg A\lor B)\land(\neg C\to B)\land((D\land C)\to A)\text{ by Conjunction 1,2,3}$$
$$\text{(First apply Logical equivalences $p\to q\equiv \neg p\lor q$)}$$
$$\text{(Then keep applying Distributive laws)}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\text{(You will get the following)}$$
$$((\neg A\land C)\lor B)\land ((A\lor \neg C)\lor \neg D)$$
$$\text{(Apply Logical equivalences $p\to q\equiv \neg p\lor q$ backward)}$$
$$(\neg B\to(\neg A\land C))\land((\neg A\land C)\to\neg D)$$
$$\text{(Applying Hypothetical syllogism)}$$
$$\neg B\to\neg D$$

---

Here is a proof with natural deduction, one might also get some ideas from this:
$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$
$$\fitch{~~1.~\neg A\lor B\\~~2.~\neg C\to B\\~~3.~(D\land C)\to A}
{\fitch{~~4.~\neg B}
{\fitch{~~5.~D}
{\fitch{~~6.~\neg A}{\fitch{~~7.~C}{~~8.~D\land C\hspace{10ex}{\land~}\textsf{Intro}~5,7\\~~9.~A\hspace{14.5ex}{\to}\textsf{Elim}~3,8\\~~10.~\bot\hspace{13.4ex}{\bot~}\textsf{Intro}~6,9}\\~~11.~\neg C\hspace{15.5ex}{\neg~}\textsf{Intro}~7-10\\~~12.~B\hspace{17ex}{\to}\textsf{Elim}~2,11}\\\fitch{~~13.~B}{~~14.~B\hspace{17ex}{}\textsf{Reit}~13}\\~~15.~B\hspace{20.5ex}{\lor~}\textsf{Elim}~1,6-12,13-14\\~~16.~\bot\hspace{20.5ex}{\bot~}\textsf{Intro}~4,15}\\~~17.~\neg D\hspace{22.5ex}{\neg~}\textsf{Intro}~5-16}\\~~18.~\neg B\to\neg D\hspace{18.5ex}{\to}\textsf{Intro}~4-17}$$